# Return specific error based on exception in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Consider a controller endpoint like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var resource = _myService.GetSomeResource();
    return Ok(resource);
}
```

The `GetSomeResource()` method performs validation on the identity of the caller, like this:

```
public SomeResourceModel GetSomeResource()
{
  _securityVerifier.VerifyCallerHasAccess();

  // do stuff to get resource

  return resource;
}
```

Within the `VerifyCallerHasAccess()` method, let's pretend that the caller does NOT have access to the resource they requested. So, we throw an exception. Something like:

```
    throw new SecurityException($"User does not have access to this resource");
```

With all that said, what I want is for the ASP.NET controller to automatically return a 403 when an exception of that type is encountered. By default, it's just returning a 500. Is it possible to register http response codes to specific types of exceptions? If so, how?

(Note, I know I can wrap my endpoint code in a try/catch, but I don't want to have to manually do this)

---

Edit for some clarity: My endpoint is already using .NET's authorization system. The security verification in question deals with getting the user's identity and checking against an external security service that they have the appropriate access rights to a given security resource.

Comment: Don't throw an exception for things that can easily be anticipated like that. This can be solved easily by returning a different object that indicates the user isn't authorized to access the resource.

Comment: ASP.Net has a whole authentication/authorization system which you should leverage rather than trying to work against it with exceptions.

Comment: @gunr2171 If the authorization logic depends on some of an entity fetched from database during the service call, the built in authorization system would not help OP.

Comment: @mason Throwing exceptions in e.g. context of DDD is a perfectly valid and convenient approach if you consider the performance penalty involved carefully. That being said, returning a result object is also fine but not necessary.

Comment: @benyogyerek you can run a query on the database during an Authorization handler.

Comment: Authentication is supposed to happen *before* an action is invoked. If `GetSomeResource()` fails it means the application itself has a problem. If a remote resource refuses a connection, it's the application that failed. A 403 means that the user has no permission to call `Get()`, not that the application failed to call a remote service

Comment: @benyogyerek both your comments are wrong. This has nothing to do with DDD to begin with and the built-in authorization middleware can be customized to do anything you can imagine. You can create a fully custom middleware if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some middleware in the request pipeline:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and then register that in Program.cs:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could modify `VerifyCallerHasAccess()` method,you could return (or set some property) true or false instead of throw an exception

in controller,you could try as below:

```
if (result)            
{                
return Ok();            
}            
else            
{                
return Problem(detail: "User does not have access to the resource", statusCode: 403);                
// you could also try return Forbind() to return a 403 with out  the detail
//check the controllerbase class and you would find more methods related            
    }
```

if you insist on throw exception, then put

```
var resource = _myService.GetSomeResource();
return Ok(resource)
```

into try catch block ,return 403 with Forbind() method or other methods you would find in controllerbase class

Answer (score -1):

You can write an exception filter (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or if you want to standardize your responses as well, take a look at [Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware)

Comment: ASP.NET Core already converts request validation errors into a ProblemDetails response *before* the action is invoked for the same reason authorization is done before an action is invoked - why waste resources processing a request that's guaranteed to fail? An action can return an explicit ProblemDetails response if it wants